# How to generate coordinate system in c#?

Tags: c#

here's my coordinate system: http://rubidium-style.com/upload/naburus_primus/grid.png

The size is 5*5. I would love to generate all the coordinates in c# that you can see on the picture. How can I do that?
I increase the following cell with 25, all the time.
This is how my code looks like at the moment, but it works only in one direction. It has to be dynamic, so it should works properly in case I increase the 5*5 to 100*100 as well.

Code:

```
int landSize = 5;
int landRegion = landSize * landSize;
int landDist = 25; // 25 cm, (1 cell size) 

for (int i=0; i<landRegion; i++){ 

   int[] x;
   const int y = 0; 
   int[] z;
   Debug.Log(x[i]); 
   Debug.Log(z[i]); 

}
```

I don't want to show you my attempts to not confuse you with. I would love to load the coordinate datas into the array.

Comment: Please elaborate on the results you are getting vs. the results you were expecting.

Comment: look at a multidimension array http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx

Comment: Most likely you need to do something with nested loop. `for (var i = 0; i < landSize; i++) { for (var j = 0; j < landSize; j++) { /*Your stuff*/}}`

Comment: One for horizontal direction, one for vertical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get from a 0..24 value to values ranging from 0..4 in both x and y direction you would do this:

```
for (int i=0; i<landRegion; i++){ 
    int y = i / landSize;
    int x = i % landSize;
```

`i / landSize` will increase `y` by 1 for every `landSize` (5) values, meaning it will be 0 for region 0 through 4, 1 for 5 through 9, 2 for 10 through 14, etc.

`i % landSize` will go up by 1 for each new value of `i`, and then wrap back to 0 when it would normally reach 5, so it will follow the x-axis.

Then, to get to -2..+2, you would subtract `landSize / 2`:

```
for (int i=0; i<landRegion; i++){ 
    int y = (i / landSize) - landSize / 2;
    int x = (i % landSize) - landSize / 2;
```

Then, to get from that to -50..+50 (in 25 increments), multiply by 25 (or `landDist` in this case):

```
for (int i=0; i<landRegion; i++){ 
    int y = ((i / landSize) - landSize / 2) * landDist;
    int x = ((i % landSize) - landSize / 2) * landDist;
```

The nice properties of this way of calculating it is that if you just substitute `i` with the index of any region, you can calculate its coordinates directly, without having to do a full loop from 0 and onwards every time.

Note that this calculation will have problems with a `landSize` value that is divisible by 2, since it will not have a well-defined center. If you reduce it to 4 above, the coordinates will go from -50 to +25. You will have to decide how to handle this case and change the code accordingly.

Looking at your picture, it seems you've called the coordinate I called y for z, and have it going from +50 down to -50, so this is the final code:

```
for (int i=0; i<landRegion; i++){ 
    int z = -((i / landSize) - landSize / 2) * landDist;
    int x =  ((i % landSize) - landSize / 2) * landDist;
```

If you need to stuff it into an array for later reference, this would do:

```
int[] z = new int[landRegion];
int[] x = new int[landRegion];
for (int i=0; i<landRegion; i++){ 
    z[i] = -((i / landSize) - landSize / 2) * landDist;
    x[i] =  ((i % landSize) - landSize / 2) * landDist;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit overly verbose because of the constants but this should work for you.

```
const Int32 xMin = -50;
const Int32 xMax = +50;

const Int32 xStep = 25;

const Int32 zMin = -50;
const Int32 zMax = +50;

const Int32 zStep = 25;

for (var z = zMin; z <= zMax; z += zStep)
{
   for (var x = xMin; x <= xMax; x += xStep)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("x: {0} z: {1}", x, z);
   }
}
```

Note that this has the order for `z`reversed; `for (var z = zMax; z >= zMin; z -= zStep)` will yield the same order as depicted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Point structure to save the co ordinates and use a Point[] to use store multiple co ordinates.

using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;

```
        List<Point> arrPoint = new List<Point>();
        arrPoint.Add(new Point(10, 20));
        arrPoint.Add(new Point(15, 25));
        arrPoint.Add(new Point(20, 30));
```